# SyntaxError: Unexpected Token '<' <DOCTYPE html>

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, doctype

OMG I am tired of trying to figure this out myself. I am using the developer tools in Chrome and in Firefox and I keep getting the SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <. It keeps flagging the first line . Please tell me what I am doing wrong here, thank you! I have tried YouTube videos and W3schools.com and still unable to figure out why it continues to be thrown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Invitation Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<script>
function showFormInput() { //get data from the form
var a1 = document.getElementById('rname').value; // 'rname reference 
// id in html(not included with html you will need to add.)
var b2 = document.getElementById('orgname').value;
var c3 = document.getElementById('date').value;
var d4 = document.getElementById('web').value;
var e5 = document.getElementById('hname').value;

document.getElementById('recipientName').innerHTML = a1; // 'recipientName 
// reference name in the html
document.getElementById('organizationName').innerHTML = b2;
document.getElementById('eventDate').innerHTML = c3;
document.getElementById('websiteURL').innerHTML = d4;
document.getElementById('hostName').innerHTML = e5;
}
</script>
<body>
<header>
<div class="top">
<a class="logo" href="index.html">CapellaVolunteers<span 
class="dotcom">.org</span></a>
</div>
<nav>
<ul class="topnav">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="invitation.html" class="active">Invitation</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<section id="pageForm">
<label for="recipientName">Recipient name:</label>
<input type="text" id="rname" name="recipientName" placeholder="Enter your 
Recipient Name" />
<label for="organizationName">Organization name:</label>
<input type="text" id="orgname" name="organizationName" placeholder="Enter 
your Organization Name" />
<label for="eventDate">Event Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="date" name="eventDate" placeholder="Enter your 
Event Date" />
<label for="websiteURL">URL:</label>
<input type="text" id="web" name="websiteURL" placeholder="Enter your 
Website URL" />
<label for="hostName">Host name:</label>
<input type="text" id="hname" name="hostName" placeholder="Host Name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showFormInput()" />
</section> 
<article id="placeholderContent">
<br/>
<br/>
Hello
<span id="recipientName">recipientName</span>!
<br/>
<br/> You have been invited to volunteer for an event held by
<span id="organizationName">organizationName</span> on
<span id="eventDate">eventDate</span>. Please come to the following 
website:
<span id="websiteURL">websiteURL</span> to sign up as a volunteer.
<br/>
<br/> Thanks!
<br/> 
<br/>
<span id="hostName">hostName</span>
</article>
<footer>This events site is for IT-FP3215 tasks.</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What `Content-Type` header are you sending from the server?

Comment: Does your code still work for you?

Comment: You have a script tag that is not inside of your head or body.

Comment: Very new to JavaScript, so I am assuming you're asking me whether or not it is text/html or text/plain? I am using text/html. Does that help any? If not please dumb it down some more for me. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I have put the script tag at the bottom and I still get the same error.

Comment: Code works fine, it is just when I go to validate it using the developer tools in Chrome and FireFox (per my assignment) that I get thrown the error.

Comment: If you write the HTML(above code) on jsfiddle, do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be rendering perfectly fine to me. I would not recommend putting a script take outside of the body tag. I would put it at the very end of the  tag so that it doesn't hold up the loading of the page. In addition, I'd use "Brackets" as my code editor for projects like this. It's super useful, and you can download "Beautify" as an extension to make your code format out nicely.

Comment: I am using Brackets, but my course assignment is requiring that we validate using the developer tools in two separate browsers. The code works fine it is just the error I am getting in the validation.